# crystal report failed

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, report

I've created a crystal report with parameter,but it does not load the value. It simply shows the heading only, I mean column names only. Please check my code and correct me. And I was tried in that to load the report to pdf format, that shows an error like "load report failed". Please correct me.

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReportDocument reportdocument = new ReportDocument();
        reportdocument.Load(Server.MapPath("CrystalReport.rpt"));
        reportdocument.SetDatabaseLogon("", "", "Aravind", "MySampleDB");
        reportdocument.SetParameterValue("MRNO", TextBox1.Text);
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportdocument;
    }
    protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EXPORTREPORT();
    }
    private void EXPORTREPORT()
    {
        MemoryStream oStream;
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        ReportDocument reportdocument = new ReportDocument();
        reportdocument.Load(Server.MapPath("CrystalReort.rpt"));
        reportdocument.SetDatabaseLogon("", "", "Aravind", "MySampleDB");
        reportdocument.SetParameterValue("MRNO",TextBox1.Text);
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportdocument;

        oStream = (MemoryStream)reportdocument.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
        //oStream = (MemoryStream)crReport.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        try
        {

            //write report to the Response stream

            Response.BinaryWrite(oStream.ToArray());

            Response.End();

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Label2.Visible = true;
            Label2.Text = "ERROR:" + Server.HtmlEncode(ex.Message.ToString());


        }

        finally
        {

            //clear stream

            oStream.Flush();

            oStream.Close();

            oStream.Dispose();

        }
```

Comment: Why you are writing : reportdocument.SetDatabaseLogon("", "", "Aravind", "MySampleDB");? Have you tried : cryReportDocument.SetDatabaseLogon("UserName", "Password", "DatabaseServerName", ""); ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the name of your report is `CrystalReort.rpt`? Instead of a more common name `CrystalReport.rpt`.

Is it also located in the root of your website?

Comment: With out parameters it will load, but by search with parameter it'll not... please help me, pdf format has worked.. please help me for doing this with parameter

Answer (score 0):

Cast value to required type , if its number then Convert.ToDouble(TextBox1.Text)

Answer (score 0):

What type of MRNO is?
Also try below code, that might help you.
                    rptDoc.ExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.NoDestination;

```
                Stream getStreams = rptDoc.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
                byte[] getbytes = GetStreamAsByteArray(getStreams);

                Response.Clear();
                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", getbytes.Length.ToString());
                Response.BinaryWrite(getbytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the below code in the load event of the page.

```
if (crystalReportDoc != null)
        {
            crystalReportDoc.Close();
            crystalReportDoc.Dispose();
            GC.Collect();
        }
```

Comment: The OP did not mention any variable named "crystalReportDoc". Is that a given parameter of the event? Why would it be necessary to dispose that? Please add more information.